# Same WiFi adapter slow on desktop but fast on laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, internet-speed

*Quick disclaimer before anyone asks: I used the **exact same physical adapter** on both my relatively high-end desktop PC and a laptop. All of the WiFi tests where done at the **same location** (so nothing related to the distance to the router).*

I have been facing this issue for a few years now and have never been able to find any solution / reason for why this is happening. I bought a **TP-Link Archer T2U Nano** (I lost the original packaging so I don't really have any more info other than the text on the USB plug itself) a few years back for use in my old PC and the WiFi speeds have always been sub-par (around 30-50 Mbps) compared to my phone (a OnePlus 7T, which gets 200-300 Mbps). I also tested the internal WiFi card of a laptop, which measured speeds in the 200-250 Mbps range.

I have recently upgraded to a new computer, and since the motherboard I bought for it does not have an integrated WiFi card built-in, I am re-using this same old Archer T2U Nano adapter to be able to use internet.

My new PC measures about the same WiFi speeds as my old one (as expected, since the adapter is the same).

The crazy thing is, that when I plug this WiFi adapter into the laptop mentioned previously (and make sure to disable the internal network card so it actually uses the adapter), it is able to download at a speed of around 140 Mbps.

The only real difference between my PC and the laptop is the fact that the laptop runs Windows 11, while my PC runs Windows 10. When I bought the WiFi adapter, however, Windows 11 was not announced yet, so I doubt that would really be the difference.

The T2U Nano advertises speeds somewhere above 200 or maybe even 300 Mbps (as said, I lost the original packaging and I can't remember exactly).

While I am obviously looking to fix this issue, if anyone could point out what could possibly be the cause of this issue that would be very much appreciated as well!

**UPDATE:** I was able to reach around 140-180Mbps by connecting the adapter through a ~3m usb extension cord. However, when holding the plug (connected through said extension cable) next to the back of my PC (where I, if I was lucky enough to be able to connect to a network in the first place, would only get around 10-30 Mbps), I still get the same speeds leaving me even more puzzled that I already was before...

Comment: Where are you connecting it to your PC? Try different USB ports. The back ports are bad idea because of all the metal around them. A short USB extension might do the trick.

Comment: PC has more electronic "noise" that will interfere with wireless signals. Use an extender cable to move the device physically away from the desktop.

Comment: @DanielB I have tried both the front 3.x and 2.0 ports as well as the back 3.x and 2.0 ports - no difference.

Comment: @music2myear when i had the adapter plugged into the laptop i held the adapter right next to the usb slot of my pc i plugged the adapter into previously.

Comment: That seems odd, but ok. Was the computer turned on?

Comment: @music2myear Yes, the PC was on.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to reach around 140-180Mbps by connecting the adapter through a ~3m usb extension cord. However, when holding the plug (connected through said extension cable) next to the back of my PC (where I, if I was lucky enough to be able to connect to a network in the first place, would only get around 10-30 Mbps), I still get the same speeds leaving me even more puzzled that I already was before...